# shallow flat in scheme

Tags: scheme

There is a function that do "shallow flat"?
I mean, like the function flatten but only one () from each expression in the list

For example:

```
 (shallow flat '((1) (2) ( ( 4 5) 6)))
```

return

```
'(1 2 (4 5) 6))
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(apply append '((1) (2) ((4 5) 6)))   ;=> (1 2 (4 5) 6))
(apply append '((1) (2) (((4) 5) 6))) ;=> (1 2 ((4) 5) 6)
```

You can make it a procedure, ie:

```
(define (shallow-flatten lst)
  (apply append lst))
```

Comment: SRFI 1 also has `concatenate`, which is arguably _the_ solution to this problem.

Comment: Or if you're using Racket, `append*` will work fine, no need to import libraries

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In Guile, `concatenate` is a builtin. ;-) But yeah, the best approach depends on which implementation you use.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris suggested, you can use SRFI 1's [concatenate](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?q=concatenate#concatenate):

```
(require srfi/1) ; import the library, this is Racket's syntax
(concatenate '((1) (2) ((4 5) 6)))
```

Alternatively, in Racket you can use [append*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2a%29%29), check to see if it's available in your interpreter:

```
(append* '((1) (2) ((4 5) 6)))
```

Either way, the result is as expected and it wasn't necessary to reinvent the wheel by defining an already existing procedure:

```
=> '(1 2 (4 5) 6)
```

Comment: In fact, in Racket, `concatenate` is actually aliased to `append*`.